# Consistent Connection String Throughout DataSources

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I'm using a connecting string from my config file (as specified in my last question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364073/386869). I notice, however, if I change the connection string in the config file, and check the connection string on the DataSource's properties, it still says the old connection string. Is there a way that I can make changes in the config file propagate through to the DataSource items?

Comment: Shouldn't changing the config file should reload the app pool?

Comment: It doesn't do this automatically, it seems...is there a way to do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear asp.net temporary folder. Restart www service. Or try reloading your asp page and app pool

Comment: Does this mean that the value IS changing, it's just not updating the preview in the properties window?

Comment: Something like this:- C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework...Do change the drive(if required) and also look for the framework

Comment: All I actually had to do was Refresh the ASP page...I could swear I tried it already.

Comment: Well I really doubt about this. It might be that you have refreshed the app pool.